# Edit data from result grid

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I would like to edit data directly from result grid in ssms. eg:
When I execute `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM some_table`, I want to edit data directly from result grid.
I don't want to open `some_table` and edit from there.
I know that result grid is read-only, but maybe someone written addin for it.

Comment: Would be nice as both MySql and Oracle allow this.

Comment: @Brian it does not depend on the SGBD but on the client you are using. For example, i'm currently working on oracle, SQL Developer does not allow editing data that way but Toad does (when you substitute select * by edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit the data from within the result grid. You'd have to go via the "open table" route if you want to edit the data manually instead of using UPDATE/INSERT SQL statements.
Is there a reason you specifically want to use the result grid instead?

You can specify a query when you go via open table to limit the results if that's your reason? There's a "Show SQL Pane" button in the top toolbar you need to select (square box with "SQL" written in it).

Answer (score 1):

I have very large database (70+ GB) with so many tables.
I'm using Red Gate's SQL refactor for intellisense and few other things.
It's so boring to type in update sql statements every time I need to change single field.
It also takes some time to find that table in the Object explorer.

Intellisense doesn't work when I use "Show SQL Pane".

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to SQL Server and have used the Oracle product 'PL/SQL developer' by All Round Automations at a previous job... It would allow you to do a SELECT in the query window and then simply add "FOR UPDATE" to the end of your refined SQL SELECT and 'ta-da' you can now edit the results in a nice grid. No need to Open Table View, click the SQL button, paste in the SQL you you have been working on and then hit execute ;)

Answer (score 1):

EMS SQL Manager for SQL Server allows to update data directly inside a results grid.
This tool is boring for typing new requests (poor intellisense and error management) but fine for this. I always have the two tools opened.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the table and choose edit top 200 records, it produces a result screen with an query.

Add to this your query and then you can edit the records in the result screen.

Also you can change the 200 to a number you want (2000).

Answer (score 0):

The "results" pane is not just results.

- Results in text
- Assorted time and IO statistics
- Estimated and actual execution plans
- Row counts, Error messages, PRINT output
  etc

This is why they are separate.

[Feel free to write your own add-in](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx) :-) [Or here](http://jcooney.net/archive/2007/11/26/55358.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server ISN'T Access!

When you run a query and get the results - thats exactly what you are doing, reading the data, not opening the table for editing.  Can you imagine the necessary transactional control around allowing the results window to be edited?  The locking would probably grind SQL to a halt - I hope no-one ever writes that kind of add-in!

Comment: MySql and Oracle, or more accurately, Query Browser, SqlDev and SqlNav all accommodate editing from the table results grid.

Comment: SQL Server does it too - it's called 'Open table' (in 2005 and prior), Edit Top X rows in 2008+, but that's not what the OP wants (he said so)